# ASP.NET MVC: Submit a list using Model binding after removing an input from the middle

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, forms

Im trying to build something like this:

```
<input name="ItemsList[0].Date" />
<input name="ItemsList[1].Date" />
<input name="ItemsList[2].Date" />
<input name="ItemsList[3].Date" />
```

The inputs are generated by AngularJS using ng-repeat, and they're submitting their data correctly. But they also can be removed using Angular. And there's the problem.

When an element in the middle of the list is removed, i get something like this on HTML:

```
<input name="ItemsList[0].Date" />
<input name="ItemsList[2].Date" />
<input name="ItemsList[3].Date" />
```

The form is submitting only "ItemsList[0]" because the missing "ItemsList[1]" element bind and its reference to the next element (Linked List).

Is there a way to solve this without having to change all elements names when an element is removed?

**Ps¹.**: Im using a directive to create the "Date" bound with JQueryUI datepicker. So when the name and ID of the input is changed manually, sometimes the datepicker missfunction.

**Ps².**: The inputs are being generated like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input name="ItemsList[{{item.count}}].Date" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just generate inputs like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input name="ItemsList[{{$index}}].Date" />
</div>
```

So now when you remove a item from middle then index would automatically change posting the correct naming sequence